# Imputing techniques for missing values

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, missing-data, data-imputation

Currently, I am working on a project for which I would appreciate some feedback and opinions.

My dataset contains data about daily solar radiation from 8 stations and covers the period from 2017 to 2020. The dataset have 10 columns, one of them is the target global horizontal irradiance(GHI).

| Date | Air Temperature (Cآ°) | Air Temperature Uncertainty (Cآ°) | DHI (Wh/m2) | DHI Uncertainty (Wh/m2) | Standard Deviation DHI (Wh/m2) | DNI (Wh/m2) | DNI Uncertainty (Wh/m2) | Standard Deviation DNI (Wh/m2) | GHI (Wh/m2) | GHI Uncertainty (Wh/m2) | Standard Deviation GHI (Wh/m2) | Relative Humidity (%) | Relative Humidity Uncertainty (%) | Barometric Pressure (mB (hPa equiv)) | Barometric Pressure Uncertainty (mB (hPa equiv)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2017 | 14.3 | 0.5 | 1016.6 | 269.7 | 302.6 | 7075.4 | 1441.7 | 1063.7 | 5111.2 | 1131.5 | 218.5 | 58.7 | 3 | 789 | 4 |
| 1/2/2017 | 13.6 | 0.5 | 1723.8 | 579.7 | 852.2 | 3633.6 | 1748.5 | 2532.3 | 4087.9 | 1313.5 | 1666.1 | 73.1 | 3 | 787.7 | 3.9 |
| 1/3/2017 | 16.5 | 0.5 | 2015.2 | 602.6 | 833.9 | 5422.2 | 1607.8 | 2908.8 | 5744.1 | 1400.3 | 1471.1 | 60 | 3 | 787.2 | 3.9 |
| 1/4/2017 | 19.5 | 0.5 |  |  |  | 6293.1 | 1691.1 | 2125.8 |  |  |  | 46.3 | 3 | 788.5 | 4 |
| 1/5/2017 | 20.9 | 0.5 | 2451.5 | 186.9 | 571 | 5004.4 | 391.3 | 1562.3 | 6345.9 | 434.2 | 1021.9 | 53.5 | 3 | 788.1 | 3.9 |
| 1/6/2017 | 24 | 0.5 | 2900.9 | 253.2 | 800.4 | 5423.1 | 548.6 |  | 7080.7 | 498.3 | 802.1 | 35 | 3 |  | 3.9 |
| 1/7/2017 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/8/2017 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/9/2017 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/10/2017 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The objective of this project is to build a model that can predict the GHI, however, the data have incomplete dates across different months. as shown in the sample data above, i have data for january but 7,8,9 and 10 is missing for all columns including the target.assuming that i have data from 11 to 30  almost complete for all columns or has  missing value at the target column too.

Therefore, my first step will be to apply imputing techniques to fill in the missing values for missing days. In order to determine whether the technique I used was effective at imputing the correct values, I decided to follow the following steps:

- Choose two stations and two columns.
- Use data without missing values, converting them to nulls.
- Apply imputing techniques, then calculate the accuracy by comparing it with the actual values I have retrieved.
- If the accuracy is high, I will generalize the same technique to all stations and columns except for the target.

Because the target is the one I would like to predict, I excluded it from imputing. So can I train my model on the data without missing values in GHI(target), and test it on the data that I applied imputing techniques on it,so it will has missing values in GHI(target)?

But how i will calculate the accuracy of my model? Or does imputing have to be applied to the target column as well before building the final model?

Given that the data is time series, can the train and test not be sequenced when building the model?

or is there other methodology I can follow to Imputing the missing days values then build the predictive model?

Comment: It might be helpful to include a sample of the data, that shows what kind of data is there, and (typically) how much is missing.

Comment: @DarrenCook the data is as on the following link but daily not monthly, and number of missing days almost 25%. https://od.data.gov.sa/Data/en/dataset/solar-resource-monitoring-stations-2017-2021

Comment: If you can paste e.g. 20 lines of typical data into your question it lowers the barrier to people giving you an answer.  In the data you linked to I chose one at random, and I see one row that is blank in all columns, and one column (`Wind Speed at 3m (std dev) Uncertainty (m/s)`) that is blank for all rows. But it sounds like that is not typical of the daily data.

Comment: @DarrenCook I have updated the question and added a sample of the data. Regarding the wind column, I will drop the columns containing 100% nulls. However, I'm concerned about cases where all rows null(missing day) or the target column is null, considering the data is time-series. I don't think it's efficient to drop the entire row in such cases.